# Plotting $\omega(k_x, k_z)$ in $(\omega, k)$ plane with assumption of $k^2 = k_x^2 + k_z^2$

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm currently studying atmospheric-gravity waves and their dispersion relations.

For analysis I need to plot the dispersion function:

\begin{equation}
    \omega^4 - \omega^2\cdot C_s^2(k_x^2 + k_z^2 + \dfrac{1}{4H^2}) + (\gamma - 1)g^2\cdot k_x^2 = 0
\end{equation}
where, $C_s^2$, $H$, $\gamma$ and $g$ are some constant values.

I used `Solve` to get $\omega$ as a function of $k_x^2$ and $k_z^2$ - $\omega = \omega(k_x^2, k_z^2)$.

Code for solving:

```
   Solve[ω^4 - ω^2*(Subscript[k, x]^2 + 
        Subscript[k, z]^2 + 1/(4*H^2)) + (γ - 1)*g^2*Subscript[k, x]^2 == 0, ω]
```

What I want:

```
Plot[f, {k, 0, 20}]
```

where `f` is any solution of `Solve`. It plot nothing, because *Mathematica* didn't know about $k^2 = k_x^2 + k_z^2$ relation.

Comment: Could you please share your _Mathematica_ code and specify what are the problems you get ?

Comment: And how should I share code, when copying from *Mathematica* I get plenty of some strange additions like `\FractioBox` and `\SuperscriptBox`?

Comment: If you start with the equation I'll try to edit it so you can see how it's done.

Comment: so you want say contours of iso `kx` in the (omega,k) plane which are solution to `F(omega,k,kx)=0` above?

Comment: I've updated the question, if it isn't clear enough now - I will update further.

Comment: Here's my hack: `f[k_, w_, t_] := 
 With[{kx = k Cos[t], kz = k Sin[t]}, 
  w^4 - w^2 (kx^2 + kz^2 + 1) + kx^2]`, and then `ContourPlot3D[f[k, w, t] == 0, {k, 0, 2}, {w, 0, 2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &), Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]`, which gives http://i.stack.imgur.com/Panis.png. It looks different from @chris's result, I think because his code sometimes chooses $k_x > k$.

Comment: @m0nhawk Is the dispersion function a growth rate of instabilities? I was curious as I have equations that look similar...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty unsure about this, because I don't know much about *manifolds* and other difficult words. So I hope I learn something here too.

I use your equation with all parameters set to simple values as Chris did

```
eqn = w^4 - w^2 ((kx^2 + kz^2) + 1/4) + 2 kx^2 == 0;
```

Your second equation `k^2==kx^2+kz^2` defines a tube with different radii `k`. We could for instance look at both equations and choose `k==3`

```
contPlot = ContourPlot3D[{w^4 - w^2 ((kx^2 + kz^2) + 1/4) + 2 kx^2 == 0, 
   kx^2 + kz^2 == 9}, {kx, -5, 5}, {w, -5, 5}, {kz, -5, 5}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.3], Red], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We are interested in the intersection of both contours. What we can do here, is to parametrize `k^2==kx^2+kz^2` differently. A tube along `w` with radius `k` can expressed as the parametric equation

$$f(w,\phi)=\{k \cos(\phi), w,k \sin(\phi)\}$$

therefore we define a transformation rule

```
rule = Thread[{kx, w, kz} :> {k*Cos[phi], w, k*Sin[phi]}]

(* {kx :> k Cos[phi], w :> w, kz :> k Sin[phi]} *)
```

We can now apply this transformation and solve your initial equation for `w`. With this we get solutions for `w` which only depend on `phi` and `k`. With those solutions, we have an explicit parametrization of the curve in 3d

```
sol = Solve[eqn /. rule, w];
paramPlot = 
 ParametricPlot3D[{kx, w, kz} /. rule /. sol /. k :> 3, {phi, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red] /. Line[pts_] :> Tube[pts, 0.1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And we can of course combine them to see whether it fits with our imagination

```
Show[{contPlot, paramPlot}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What you want to have now is a plot where on the first axis is `k` and on the second `w`

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{k, w} /. sol], {k, 0, 9}, {phi, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Its only a curve because  I fixed arbitrarily one degree of freedom (I think anyway...)

Comment: and stop playing the trick of throwing lots of nice looking 3D  curves: I invented it ;o)  (just kidding nice plots and good answer!)

Comment: @chris Thanks. I see now that you set one dimension. I was just looking at your images and started trying it by myself.

Answer (score 5):

Let's give ad hoc values to your physical parameters

```
eqn = ω^4 - ω^2 ((kx^2 + kz^2) + 1/4) + 2 kx^2
```

Let's now apply the extra condition on the modulus of $k$

```
eqn= eqn /. kz -> Sqrt[k^2 - kx^2];
```

then we can find zeros of the dispersion relation at fixed `kx`

```
 Table[ContourPlot[
 eqn == 0 /. kx -> i/4 // Release, {ω, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, 
 ContourStyle -> ColorData[10][i],
 RegionFunction -> Function[{k, ω}, k > i/4], 
 FrameLabel -> {k, ω}], {i, 1, 4}] // Show
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

where I have added a cut to impose k>kx as suggested by Rahul Narain.

Alternatively, following more closely his strategy (i.e. proceed at fixed angle between 'kx' and 'ky')

```
 eqn = ω^4 - ω^2 ((kx^2 + kz^2) + 1/4) + 2 kx^2 /. 
 kx -> k Cos[θ] /. kz -> k Sin[θ]
 Table[ContourPlot[eqn == 0 /.θ-> Pi i/8 // Release, 
 {ω, 0, 2}, {k, 0,2}, ContourStyle -> ColorData[10][i], 
 FrameLabel -> {k, ω}], {i, 1, 8}] // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Using the same choice as @chris (and assuming you only want $\omega>0$, you can get the solution (in this case 2 solutions actually) as :

```
eqn[cs2_, oofh2_, gg_, kx_, kz_] = \[Omega]^4 - \[Omega]^2 cs2 ((kx^2 + kz^2) + oofh2) + gg kx^2 ;    

sol[cs2_?NumericQ, oofh2_?NumericQ, gg_?NumericQ, kx_?NumericQ, kz_?NumericQ] := 
  Solve[{eqn[cs2, oofh2, gg, kx, kz] == 0, \[Omega] >= 0}, {\[Omega]}, Reals][[All, 1, 2]]
```

Then you can simply plot it as a function of the parameters :

```
ParametricPlot[Thread[{Sqrt[kx^2 + kz^2], sol[1., 1/4., 2, kx, kz]}], {kx, -2, 2}, {kz, -2, 2}, 
          AxesLabel -> {" k ", " \[Omega] "}]
```

[image]

However you get possibly better information with a more canonical plot :

```
Plot3D[sol[1., 1/4., 2, kx, kz], {kx, 0, 5}, {kz, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {" kx ", " kz ", " \[Omega] "}]
```

[image]